# COMO ACOMODAR LAS CARDS UNA AL LADO DE OTRA CREANDO DESDE EL DOM JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Hola buenos dias me surgio un problema en el proyecto de javascript que estoy encarando de un carrito de compras, creo las cards desde el DOM pero los productos me figuran uno sobre el otro no uno al lado del otro y nose de que forma cambiarlo, adjunto el codigo y imagen de como se ve !
[image: UN PRODUCTO SOBRE EL OTRO Y NO UNO AL LADO DEL OTRO]

```
    function divTragos(tragos) {
  const productContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
  productContainer.innerHTML = '';
  tragos.forEach(item => {
      productContainer.innerHTML +=
          `<section class="store">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="items">
      <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="item shadow mb-4">
                      <h3 class="title">${item.titulo}</h3>
                      <img class="item-image" src="${item.img}">
                      <div class="item-details">
                          <h4 class="price">${item.precio}</h4>
                          <button class="item-button btn btn-primary addToCart">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>`;
  });
```

Comment: Podrías intentar dentro del section agregarle un style="display: inline". A fin de que se acomode en la misma fila.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, lo que pasa es que estas creando un elemento en el `innerHTML` con todo el `<section>` completo, lo que hace que se cree por asi decirlo una fila nueva por cada elemento, lo unico que tendrias que hacer es solamente ingresar el `item` requerido.

```js
productContainer.innerHTML += 
  `<div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="item shadow mb-4">
       <h3 class="title">${item.titulo}</h3>
       <img class="item-image" src="${item.img}">
       <div class="item-details">
         <h4 class="price">${item.precio}</h4>
         <button class="item-button btn btn-primary addToCart">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>`
```